# Using twig variable to dynamically call an imported macro sub-function

Tags: twig

I am attempting if use a variable to call a specific macro name.

I have a macros file that is being imported

```
{% import 'form-elements.html.twig' as forms %}
```

Now in that file there are all the form element macros: text, textarea, select, radio etc.

I have an array variable that gets passed in that has an elements in it:

```
$elements = array(
    array(
        'type'=>'text,
        'value'=>'some value',
        'atts'=>null,
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'text,
        'value'=>'some other value',
        'atts'=>null,
    ),
);

{{ elements }}
```

what im trying to do is generate those elements from the macros. they work just fine when called by name:

```
{{ forms.text(element.0.name,element.0.value,element.0.atts) }}
```

However what i want to do is something like this:

```
{% for element in elements %}
{{ forms[element.type](element.name,element.value,element.atts) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried the following all resulting in the same error:

```
{{ forms["'"..element.type.."'"](element.name,element.value,element.atts) }}
{{ forms.(element.type)(element.name,element.value,element.atts) }}
{{ forms.{element.type}(element.name,element.value,element.atts) }}
```

This unfortunately throws the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Attribute "value" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr".' in Twig\Environment.php on line 541
```

Any help or advice on a solution or a better schema to use would be very helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just thought other people may want the answer to this, as provide by fabpot:

> This is indeed something that is not supported: calling a macro with a dynamic name (I have added a proper exception to be clearer about the issue).
>
> If you really want to do that, you can do so with the following code:
>
> {{ attribute(forms, element.type, [element.name,element.value,element.atts]) }}
>
> -fabpot

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/922#issuecomment-11133299

Comment: In Twig 2, this is no longer a solution :( from what I understand, for security reasons attribute cannot access templates.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic macros may not be supported in Twig.

But there is a simple workaround since you can **dynamically include** other templates.

Example:
Let's say you have a bunch of content modules or content blocks (or however you wanna call them) for your site. And you have Twig macros responsible of rendering each of these modules.

```
{# modules.twig #}

{% macro module1(config) %}
  <div>module one</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro module2(config) %}
  <div>module two</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro module3(config) %}
  <div>module three</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Now, what you need to dynamically call these macros is to add an extra template for each, like so:

```
{# module1.twig #}

{% import "modules.twig" as modules %}
{{ modules.module1(config) }}
```

```
{# module2.twig #}

{% import "modules.twig" as modules %}
{{ modules.module2(config) }}
```

```
{# module3.twig #}

{% import "modules.twig" as modules %}
{{ modules.module3(config) }}
```

Finally, in your actual page template you just include the template instead of calling the macro.

```
{# template.twig #}

{# this is the macro's name to be called #}
{% set macro = 'module2' %}
{# this is just a config object to be passed to the macro #}
{% set config = {} %}

{% include macro ~ '.twig' with { config: config } only %}
```

Et voilá, (dynamically produced) output will be `<div>module two</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Twig `template_from_string()` function is enabled in your environment, you can accomplish this with something like:

```
{% set macroName  = 'bing' %}
{% set tmplString = "{% import 'macros.twig' as macros %}{{ macros.#{macroName}( arg1, arg2 ) }}"

{{ include(
    template_from_string(tmplString),
    { arg1: 'bong', arg2: 'bang' }
) }}
```

Basically, the same as @Arvid's answer, but lets you create the template in a string and include it dynamically instead of having to create separate files.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html